# How to configure Pycharm to prevent adding configuration for each files

Tags: python, pycharm

I just get started learning Python using Pycharm IDE, and I noticed that whenever I want to create a new file, I have to add a configuration for each individual new file I just created. Such as setting up the script name, etc. It's this the way it supposes to be, or can I reuse the same configuration for each new file I create?

[image]

**Goal**

1. Create new sample.py in my project directory
2. add a `print("hello")` to the sample.py
3. click the run button
4. print out the `hello` on the console

(without clicking the Edit Configuration Button)

Answer (score 0):

I have the button for running and debugging in the Toolbar, if you don't see the toolbar, turn it on by doing: View -> Toolbar

Then click with the right mouse button on `sample.py` and `run sample.py`, after the first run the default run/debug buttons should appear on the toolbar.

You should see something like this:

[image: toolbar buttons]

Comment: Do you mean the green arrow button on the right top corner?

Comment: I understand, but i don't get the configuration dynamically. I have to manually clicked edit configuration and supply the path for my script first. Use that configuration, and then I'm able to run my script.

Comment: You don't need to create a configuration, after first run PyCharm should to it automatically for you. Of course you need a configuration for every python file if they are not related in a project, like a Django project.